# Apply space between divs

Tags: html, css

The below two divs appear one next to other, the content of which are populated dynamically and the data is very long in both the divs.

My question is that how to add some space between the two divs?

```
  <div name="qt" id="qt" style='width:50%;float:left;display:inline;overflow:auto;height:500px;border:1px solid #ccc;'> </div>
     <div id="data" name="data" style='overflow:auto;width:35%;height:500px;margin-left:0px;border:1px solid #ccc;'></div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can add on css `#qt {margin-right:10px;}`

you can change the number of pixels you wish.

Answer (score 2):

change `margin-left:0px` on the 2nd `<div/>` to a greater value

Answer (score 1):

Float the second `div` left, and change its `margin-left` to a non-zero value, e.g.:

```
<div name="qt" id="qt" style='width:50%;float:left;display:inline;overflow:auto;height:500px;border:1px solid #ccc;'> </div>
 <div id="data" name="data" style='overflow:auto;width:35%;height:500px;margin-left:50px;border:1px solid #ccc; float: left;'></div>
```